# Parsing a string to complex class

Tags: java, regex, string, class, parsing

I have a `Filters` class that is extended by 2 other classes

```
public class Filters {
}

public class SimpleFilter extends Filters {
    FilterAttribute A;
    FilterOperator  op;
    String value;
}

public class ComplexFilter extends Filters {
    Filters filterA;
    Filters filterB;
    Conjunction c;
}
```

I have a string like:

```
String filters = "(((CreationT>1234)and(LastM<567))or(LastM<=8910))";
```

I need to parse this string to a `ComplexFilter`. Which again has a `ComplexFilter` for `"((creationT>1234)and(LastM<567))/*This complex filter has 2 simple filters and conjunction 'and'*/"`, a SimpleFilter for `"(LastM<=8910)"` and a conjunction `or`.

What would be the best approach to do so? Stuck with this from hours.

Comment: What would be the expected output from your example input string?

Comment: Because you have nested parenthesws, really an expression, the best thing to do would be to use a parser.  Have a look at Javaluator, which is an open source expression parser.

Comment: Asking for "the best" very often indicates that your question is kinda off topic. Because in real life, there is rarely something clearly "the best". Most often, there are just many options and opinions. Where, in this case, I agree with Tim - when your strings carry such complex syntax/semantic; you better look into creating a **parser** for it.

Comment: @shubham gupta, which library does this FilterAttribute, FilterOperator , Filters belong to ??